# Do plastics lower testosterone?

Tags: nutrition, plastic, testosterone

I've read articles online claiming food or liquids that come in contact with plastic and then are consumed, lowers testosterone.

Articles I've read:

https://www.webmd.com/men/news/20140814/common-chemicals-may-lower-testosterone-levels-study-finds

https://www.anabolicmen.com/plastic-testosterone/

But then I've also read some articles somewhat contradicting this:
http://theconversation.com/are-plastics-making-men-infertile-43751

I'm wondering if there are any studies that can give a final conclusion to this?

EDIT: I'm talking about plastics that we come in contact with every day. For example:

- Plastic bottles
- Plastic food containers
- Plastic wrap around vegetables and meat
- Plastic lining in cans
- Plastic sanitary pipes in our homes (PVC)

Most of these plastics contain chemicals like BPA, DEHP or DBP. I'm curious if and how these chemicals (and potential other chemicals in the products listed) lower testosterone, when their contents are consumed.

Comment: The first link is about phthalates. The second is about phthalates, BPA, and other xenoestrogens. The third link is about phthalates. I wonder if we can safely restrict this question just to phthalates and the plastics that contain them, so responding becomes more feasible.

Comment: Oh, this is your first question? [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users)

Comment: Thanks and thanks for the link. I'll add some more text to it. I don't really know what you mean but what I just want to know if general plastics like we come in contact with any day, will lower testosterone.

Comment: I understand, but because we come into contact with so many plastics (and the sorts of plastics that are used in food containers have changed over time), and they *might* emit so many chemicals, it is difficult to easily answer. The first and last links are far more specific. They talk about one particular chemical, so it is far more likely we can point to studies on that particular chemical to show whether or nor it is really emitted by plastics and whether or not it really affects testosterone.

Comment: ["Plastic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic#Bakelite) is a **much** too wide categorisation of substances to be able to give any kind of definitive answer. For instance natural latex ("rubber") and Bakelite are both "plastic". You need to narrow the question down to some **specific** plastic substances or this question cannot be answered.

Comment: I understand, I'll adjust the question when I get back home

Comment: I think it's more that they raise oestrogen levels than lower testosterone. I read several studies to that effect more that 10 years ago.

Comment: @Richard - I was just going to ask about mimicking estrogen vs. suppressing testosterone, because that was my own, albeit somewhat outdated, understanding of the claim of what plastics do.

Answer (score 2):

In [Bisphenol A may cause testosterone reduction by adversely affecting both testis and pituitary systems similar to estradiol](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378427410000561) *Toxicology Letters*, 
Volume 194,15 April 2010, Pages 16-25, it is reported that in rat studies Bisphenol A reduces testosterone levels in both testis and plasma by statistically significant amounts.

> Both BPA and E2 treatments decreased plasma and testicular testosterone levels

[Bisphenol A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisphenol_A) (BPA) is a monomer used to make polycarbonate, which is one type of plastic.  Some BPA remains unpolymerized in the plastic, such as plastic bottles, and can leach out and be consumed (see [BPA, chemical used to make plastics, found to leach from polycarbonate drinking bottles Into humans](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/news/press-releases/bpa-chemical-plastics-leach-polycarbonate-drinking-bottles-humans/)).

Comment: Also note: the rats in the study did not eat BPA, it was injected subcutaneously.

Comment: @GEdgar ok, I added this reference https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/news/press-releases/bpa-chemical-plastics-leach-polycarbonate-drinking-bottles-humans/ which is announcing this paper https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2737011/

Comment: How do the amounts in this study compare to the amounts we would ingest from food stored in plastic containers?

Comment: @PaulJohnson: The amounts injected (!) were much higher than what you would expect to ingest (!) via plastic-stored food. (The abstract lists the amounts administered.) But the focus of this study were the _mechanisms_ by which BPA affects the body, not the quantification of BPA intake.

Comment: @PaulJohnson In the first reference in the answer, 100mg/kg/day was the lowest level of BPA where testosterone was shown to decrease statistically significantly.  This is much high than what would come from using polycarbonate to drink water.

Comment: ...within the 6 weeks of the study. It's far too easy to assume (or dismiss) effects of long-term, low-dosage exposure based on short-term, high-dosage studies. I think the answer is good as-is; lifting actual dosage numbers into the answer would probably lead to just such assumptions, as opposed to the "we don't really know one way or the other" which is actually the case (barring the unearthing of applicable long-term studies).